# Some beginners eclipse questions

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have recently ditch Dreamweaver as my IDE for my web projects and I'm currently using Eclipse. My current web project is written in PHP, but I'm not so familiar with Eclipse yet. I downloaded the Eclipse PDT. which has all the PHP developer plugins. And my first questions when I start a project does it mean I'm creating a root folder? and shall I choose PHP project or static web project? I've choosed the PHP project,but I just need to know that I'm not choosing the wrong one.

And why is it showing an error(an exclamation mark) when I try to add some javascripts to my index.php file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/addTools.js"></script>
```

when I hoover over the exclamation mark I get the following info:

Multipel annotation found at this line:
-starttag of element script
-undefined attribute name (src)
-undefined attribute name (type)
-endtag of element script

As far as I know I have used the correct syntax for adding external javascripts to a html. Seems like a bug?

I can still run the website but it is just an annoying moment, pls help me anyone?

REQUESTED SCREEN DUMP:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static web project is for a web project with only html pages. No dynamic pages with php for instance. You choose the good one.
The syntax seems correct, could you show us the full code, or even a screenshot of your editor? It seems the editor is not aware about the html dtd.

Comment: Yes look above! Sorry for the late response.

Comment: oh I used doctype as <!DOCTYPE HTML> which I think is the HTML 5 standard

Comment: Thanks i used the <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> now and the marks disappeared but does it have any implications on my html code? I don't think I have any html-5 elements but I have som CSS 3.

Comment: I think the html parser in the editor does not support html 5 now, which really is a shame. see this post : http://superuser.com/questions/142997/enable-html5-tags-on-eclipse